# Rails / ActiveRecord controller boilerplate (call to .all)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have the following boilerplate in a Cars controller

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController

# GET /cars
# GET /cars.json
def index
  @cars = Car.all

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @cars }
  end
end
```

Let's say I have 50,000 cars in my database.

My understanding is that each call to `/cars/index` will query the db (`select * from cars`), and build an object to store all that info.  Then the Cars view would have access to `@cars`, and a json request would simply get a giant json response including all 50k cars.

1. This default behavior sounds like a horrible idea in my situation. What if `/cars` is a very popular page? What if I had 10 million cars?
2. I don't use `@cars` in the view (`index.html.erb`), so how can I verify that I don't need
   any json calls? (Does Rails need this for some reason I'm unaware
   of?)

It seems that `@cars = Car.all` is a very uncool line of code only used to validate that your new controller is working, and should probably be removed right in the beginning. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you should not want to display all "Cars" on a single page. Some filtering should occur before displaying the results. The most widespread solution would be to "paginate" the results for large datasets. Depending on implementation this should happen before the actual object is fetched from the database.

have a look at

https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/wiki

Comment: /cars/index doesn't display any cars at all.  This means I can remove the `@cars = Car.all` line and save lots of resources, right?

Comment: Yes. If you do nothing with them then you an just delete them. Keep in mind that the Rails scaffolding is there to show you how stuff is done but controller actions like 'index' should/could not be used in (big db) production systems.

Comment: Thanks Max.  How do I know if the json aspect is being used?  If I needed `@cars` for the json, could I put the Car.all line inside the format.json curly braces?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all, you should use `@car = Car.scoped`. It will return an active record relation which will lazy-load car objects only when they are needed. Highly memory efficient.

For example, if you need only thirty cars from the `@cars` variable which is supposed to have all cars in database, `@cars.limit(30)` will load only those many.

On the other hand, if you used `@cars = Car.all` and then try `@cars[0..29]`, all cars get loaded  into `@cars` anyway which will bloat the memory.

Excuse my english. I am finding it hard to type straight at the moment.

Comment: "which will bloat the memory"  This is what I'm trying to avoid.  Since I don't even use `@cars` in the view, it seems best to just delete the call to Car.all.

Comment: What exactly do you need index action for if not index the cars?

Comment: If you do not want to use html views, just replace the whole respond_to block with `render json: @cars`. This is assuming you want to set this up as an api.